# How can I group target dependencies in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a pretty complicated `make`-based project that I'm trying to migrate to modern CMake usage instead. In the `Makefile`, I have several similar shared library targets that share mostly-identical compile flags. So, it would look something like this:

```
add_library(lib1 SHARED src1.cpp src2.cpp)
target_compile_options(lib1 PUBLIC -public-flag1 -public-flag2 -unique-flag3 PRIVATE -private-flag)

add_library(lib2 SHARED src3.cpp src4.cpp) 
target_compile_options(lib2 PUBLIC -public-flag -public-flag2 PRIVATE -private-flag)
```

Is there some way I can abstract out the common dependencies so I don't have to repeat them under each target? It would seem that an [Interface Library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) would be the way to do this, something like:

```
add_library(common_options INTERFACE)
target_compile_options(common_options 
    PUBLIC -public-flag1 -public-flag2
    PRIVATE -private-flag
)
add_library(lib1 SHARED src1.cpp src2.cpp)
target_compile_options(lib1 PUBLIC -unique-flag3)
target_link_libraries(lib1 common_options)

add_library(lib2 SHARED src3.cpp src4.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(lib1 common_options)
```

which would be a net win for maintainability in my opinion. However, CMake throws an error at this, complaining that an interface target can only carry `INTERFACE` options (I can't add the `PRIVATE` options to it). Is there a different way to do this that would allow me to encapsulate the `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE` flags that are shared among targets?

Comment: Can't you set a variable to be whatever you want and expand it when calling `target_compile_options`

Comment: Or you may to write a function/macro which creates a library and setup common properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Consider this:

```
add_library(public  INTERFACE)
add_library(private INTERFACE)
target_compile_options(public  INTERFACE -Werror)
target_compile_options(private INTERFACE -Wall)

target_link_libraries(lib1
    PUBLIC  # <-- public's flags will be applied to lib1 and any targets linking to lib1
        public
    PRIVATE # <-- private's flags will only be applied to lib1
        private
)
```

In short, you forgot to add scopes in your calls to `target_link_libraries`.

**Update**:

> So I think the direct answer to my question is that I can't do exactly what I want, which would be to encompass both private and public compile option dependencies into a single entity. Instead, I just have to make a public one and a private one. Not quite as clean as what I'd hoped, but manageable.

Not really, you will always have to specify `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE` scope, but if you are willing to use `target_compile_options` instead of interface libraries to achieve this, then this would also work:

```
set(COMMON_FLAGS
    PUBLIC
        -Werror
        -ffast-math
    PRIVATE
        -Wall
)

target_compile_options(lib1 ${COMMON_FLAGS})
target_compile_options(lib2
    ${COMMON_FLAGS}
    PUBLIC # <-- you can still set scoped flags
        -fno-fast-math
)
```

In my opinion, however, using interface libraries and just deal with the fact that you have to use `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE` is both cleaner and more maintainable in the longer run.

Btw, if you want to compact `COMMON_FLAGS` to a single line: `set(COMMON_FLAGS "PUBLIC;-Werror;-ffast-math;PRIVATE;-Wall")`

Comment: Thanks. So I think the direct answer to my question is that I can't do exactly what I want, which would be to encompass both private and public compile option dependencies into a single entity. Instead, I just have to make a public one and a private one. Not quite as clean as what I'd hoped, but manageable.

Comment: @JasonR Updated my answer. It is possible, if you consider a variable a single entity. I'm not aware of any other ways to achieve what you want.